# How to fix jQuery DataTables not rendering correctly a 'bootstrap toggle-switch' when using responsive plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

Bootstrap toggle-switch is working fine when the browser is in normal state. However, when resizing the browser, the bootstrap toggle-switch no works properly. In fact, there is no bug.

*Datatables script:*

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                pageLength: 10,
                responsive: true,
                columnDefs: [{
                    targets: [0],
                    data: "active",
                    className: "dt-body-center",
                    render: function (data, type, row) {return RenderToggle(data, type, row, state=1)}    
                },
                {
                    targets: [7],
                    data: "specific",
                    className: "dt-body-center",
                    render: function (data, type, row) {return RenderToggle(data, type, row, state=0)}    
                },
            ],
                order: [[1, 'asc']],

                rowCallback: function (row, data) {
                    $('input.toggle-switch', row).prop('checked', data.active == 1).bootstrapToggle({ size: 'mini' });
                }

            });

            function RenderToggle(data, type, row, state) {
                let chk = state == 1 ? "checkbox" : "checkbox-inactive";
                if (type === 'display') {
                    return '<input type= "'+ chk +'" class="toggle-switch" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-style="mr-1" data-size="xs">';
                }
                    return data;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

**Normal**: Browser is maximized

[image: Browser is maximized]

**Problem**: Browser resizes and toggle-switch is not rendered

[image: Browser resizes and toggle-switch is not rendered]

**Testcase**: [live.datatables.net/nadeyaxe/1/edit](https://live.datatables.net/nadeyaxe/1/edit)

I tried to use [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/exvht7ou/) that renders a custom control, but I can't figure out how to make it work using a toggle switch.

**Expected result**: Working use case

[image: Working use case:]